# In Blazor server - a component to provide a carousel

Tags: bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a Blazor server app using DevExpress components for most of the components. However, I have two needs they don't cover and so what is available to do the following? Both bootstrap & MudBlazor seem to have a carousel component but it's not clear how well they work for gestures/swipes in a Blazor server app.

My specific needs are:

1. To have a page like the iPhone home screen where it has `o o O o` that shows you have 4 pages and are on the third page. And you then swipe left/right to go to a different page.
2. Have a page like the Tinder UI where you have a single page (so not a carousel) that you can swipe left/right on and when the user does, I repopulate the page's data with the next record.

What's out there for this that works great in Blazor (server) and feels like a phone app when running on a phone in terms of gestures.